# Getting method not found in google my business api

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-my-business-api

I have to try to fetch review using google my business API but I am getting method not found.
If I use the post method then it returns null.
Here is my curl code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_end_point_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. $authorization,'Content-Type: application/json'));
$data1 = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
dd(curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: it might be helpful if you share `$api_end_point_url` here, just remove any id or access token if there is any .

Comment: Here is the url `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts` @PooyaEstakhri

Comment: this is not a solution for your question but shouldn't your last line be `dd($data1);`

btw to me it seems the problem is not because of this code but probably a problem in your app settings or setting wrong access tokens

Comment: It's just print_r function which print array it is default laravel function @PooyaEstakhri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue.
By mistake i was used other gmail which don't have google my business access.
For that reason API returns method not found.